# Angular CLI shows error for every command

Tags: angular

Any command I try, I get: "You need to specify a command before moving on" error.
Seems like ng is recognized (because that's not a system error) but, internally, ng does not recognize it's commands.

[image]

[image]

I tried to globally uninstall Angular, to update to the last version, restart the machine. The error continues.

Comment: I wonder what does ng on your path actually stand for

Comment: type `where ng`

Comment: I would say it is not that  *ng does not recognize it's commands.* but rahter commands are not passed to `ng` binary at all

Comment: where ng shows: C:\Users\\[myuser]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng.js,
C:\Users\\[myuser]\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng,
C:\Users\\[myuser]\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tnx to Antoniosss for giving a hint which helped to find a solution.

Writing "where ng" in the command line, I found that my Angular CLI was referring to one of these paths:

- C:\Users[myuser]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng.js
- C:\Users[myuser]\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng
- C:\Users[myuser]\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd

When I executed angular from .@angular\cli\bin, the problem was exactly as described.

When I executed from .\npm\ng, it worked fine.

So, the solution was to edit the system path to remove the first route and add the second one.

After editing, restart the machine to take effect.